# Issue with IF statement attaching to canvas object - JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

l do believe to have an issue regarding an if statement that allows for the detection of where the canvas object, being the image that displays , should be located at within the canvas. There is a reproducible demo provided.

**NOTE: I do want to ***KEEP*** the css alignment, `canvasauto`, and not remove it if possible.**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var the_button = document.getElementById("the_button");
var the_background = document.getElementById("the_background");

var imageXpos = 500;
var imageYpos = 300;
var imageWidth = 110;
var imageHeight = 80;

var imagecheck_Xpos = canvas.width - imageXpos;
var imagecheck_Ypos = canvas.height - imageYpos;

window.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_button, imagecheck_Xpos, imagecheck_Ypos, imageWidth, imageHeight);
}

the_button_function = (event) => {
  const {
    x,
    y
  } = event;
  /* l believe the issue is here */
  if ((x >= imagecheck_Xpos && x < (imagecheck_Xpos + imageWidth)) &&
    (y >= imagecheck_Ypos && y < (imagecheck_Ypos + imageHeight))) {
    alert("<Button>")

  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => the_button_function(e));
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.canvasauto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c" width="970" height="550" class="canvasauto"></canvas>

<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `x` from the `MouseEvent`. This is an experimental feature which is [an alias of `clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/x).

The [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) property gives the coordinates ***relative to the application's viewport***.

You probably want [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX), which is ***relative to (the padding edge of the) target node***.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var the_button = document.getElementById("the_button");
var the_background = document.getElementById("the_background");

var imageXpos = 500;
var imageYpos = 300;
var imageWidth = 110;
var imageHeight = 80;

var imagecheck_Xpos = canvas.width - imageXpos;
var imagecheck_Ypos = canvas.height - imageYpos;

window.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_button, imagecheck_Xpos, imagecheck_Ypos, imageWidth, imageHeight);
}

the_button_function = (event) => {
  const {
    offsetX: x,
    offsetY: y
  } = event;
  /* l believe the issue is here */
  if ((x >= imagecheck_Xpos && x < (imagecheck_Xpos + imageWidth)) &&
    (y >= imagecheck_Ypos && y < (imagecheck_Ypos + imageHeight))) {
    alert("<Button>")

  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => the_button_function(e));
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.canvasauto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c" width="970" height="550" class="canvasauto"></canvas>

<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```